# Is Braid on PS3/PC different in any way? Is there a definitive choice?

Tags: version-differences, braid

I'm one of the few poor souls who hasn't played Braid yet. I don't have an Xbox so my choices are PS3 or PC. The game came out on both platforms a little while after the xbox version, so I was wondering if the content on all three is the same.

Are there extra levels or anything in the PS3 or PC versions? Are the graphics different/higher resolution on PC? Any other notable differences?

Also, (this part of the question is more subjective) I don't have a game pad for the PC, so it'd be played on my keyboard. Does it play ok like this or is this enough of a reason to go with the PS3 version?

Comment: I'd get it on PC through Steam. Because Steam rocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're all exactly the same.  And since Braid only has 2 speeds of movement (moving or stopped) I can't imagine it being very different gameplay-wise on either platform.

I personally own the game on the Xbox 360, and think it's great!  I'd probably have to suggest going with the PS3 version of the game, because the Gamepad is a nice way to layout the controls.

Braid is all about the puzzles, and art style, but the audio track is nice too, so you may want to take into account the quality of the sound system[s] you have your PC and PS3 set up with as well.

It might be interesting to note that on [Gamespot](http://www.gamespot.com/search.html?qs=braid&om_act=convert&om_clk=search), Braid for Xbox 360 and PS3 received a 9.2/10 critic score, where the PC game "only" received 9.1/10.  A slight difference, to be sure, but it's there.

Also, please read the comment below by 'RiMMER', as it mentions a few minor details that are different between versions.  In general however, the games are wholly identical.

Comment: The score discrepancy might have to do with controls on keyboard vs. gamepad

Comment: I'd like to point out that they are **not** the same. The rabbit above the ladder in the level "Irreversible" behaves differently between the PS3/XBOX360 versions and the PC version. Also, in "Crossing the gap" you can perform the ladder jump in the console versions, but not in the PC version.

Answer (score 5):

Essential Braid seems to be the same on all platforms (PC/XBox360/PS3). Same levels, same achievements (12).

I don't know about the console games, but I can add that Braid Steam version implements two useful Steamworks features:

- **Steam Cloud**: that allows you to store your savegames online ("in cloud") so that you can continue your worlds traverse from other PCs (or from the same if you accidentally lose data on your HDD)
- **Steam Play**: that allows you to play also from Mac with your digital copy

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, the "standard" game should be the same on every platform, but one thing to keep in mind is that the PC version [allows for playing (and building) custom levels](http://braid-game.com/news/?p=576). I have no idea how many are out there currently, but there's definitely some potential there that isn't present on the console versions.

Answer (score 2):

All versions of the game are the same.  I personally own the PC version through Steam and I loved it.  I played through the whole game with the keyboard and it worked out very well.  Since you already have a PS3 though, if you did want to play it on the PC, but using a controller, there are a lot of free resources on the web that allow you to use your PS3 controller on your PC like any other PC gamepad with minimal effort.  The one I have specifically used that is painless to install and setup is available through a company called MotionInJoy.  You can find their download page [here](http://www.motioninjoy.com/download).