# How do I set up Braid to use a gamepad on PC?

Tags: pc, braid, motioninjoy-ds3tool

So I asked [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/19681/8090) about Braid on PC/PS3 a while back, and one of the answers pointed me to the MotionInJoy drivers that allows PS3 controllers to be used on a PC. I've installed them properly and have used my DualShock 3 in a few games, but I can't figure out how to enable it when I'm playing Braid!

There doesn't seem to be any menu item to select an input type, which begs the question - is Braid not detecting my controller for some reason, or does Braid simply not allow you to use anything but the keyboard for input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Braid is described on Steam as having support for the Xbox 360 controller, which MotionJoy is able to emulate. Try using that.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [JoyToKey](http://www.electracode.com/4/joy2key/JoyToKey%20English%20Version.htm) and map keypresses to your PS3 gamepad. I never played Braid so I don't know much about its input support.

Answer (score 0):

I own Logitech F710 which has a switch between DirectInput and XInput:

[image]

Setting it to XInput resolved that problem, thanks @kotekzot