# How do I get Braid to recognize my Xbox 360 controller?

Tags: pc, controllers, braid

Supposedly *Braid* has support for the Xbox 360 controller (as it's an XBLA port), but it refuses to recognize mine.  The controller shows up among my Devices & Printers, and works perfectly in *Super Meat Boy*, but *Braid* is totally oblivious.

**Edit:** It somehow **fixed itself** after I played *SMB*, but I have no idea how.  I didn't unplug/replug it between *Braid*, *SMB* and back again (though I had much earlier), or really do anything else at all.

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/51119/15772

Comment: @QAzer only tangentally (if at all); that is about non-native support.

Comment: Lets get down to business shall we? Is this a wired or wireless controller? Have you tried removing all connected devices (including mouse and keyboard) except the controller and testing it?